# Link2SD fails for application updates

Tags: updates, link2sd

I have rooted my Xperia M and installed Cyanogenmod 11 (Android 4.4.4). Since the internal memory of my device is limited, I am using Link2SD (3.5.2 free) to link apps on my SD card.

The problem I am facing is when linked apps are updated they just disappear from the installed apps list. Shortcuts on my app drawer say "App not installed". However, the data for the updated apps is still on the SD card (`Link2SD -> Cleanup 2nd Partition -> Details`).

I have enabled Auto Link on Link2SD, yet whenever Android tries to updates any linked app, it ends up deleting it. How can I fix it? If the problem is with Link2SD then what alternative apps are available?